# Will DX10.1 rated motherboard run DX11 graphics card?

Tags: motherboard, gpu

I have H61 m DS2 which is rated with dx 10.1 but if i use a dx 11 graphics card like GT730 1GD5(asus) will my motherboard support? please reply..

Comment: Your motherboard will support any PCI Express 3.0 x16 graphics card.  PCI Express 3.0 is also backwards compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Your motherboard supports DX 10.1 for the onboard graphics and has no relation to your external card. So yes, it will support a DX11 card (onboard graphics will be disabled).